# How to move specific commit from git branch A history to git branch B from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, git-cherry-pick

I am using cherry-pick but it is telling me the change has been already included.

Example: I have total of 10 commits in branch A but I want to move only commits no 1, 7 and 9 to branch B.

How do I achieve this in eclipse?

Comment: `git cherry-pick` is the way to do this. Can you show your `git log` for both branches so we can see what the two branches look like?

Comment: i am right clicking on specific commit and selecting cherry peek in eclipse but it is telling me already included.

Comment: how to achieve cherry pick from eclipse plugin. and iam following the ways how some one shared in stack but still iam facing problems

Comment: I don't know anything about eclipse. But, in general, you should checkout branch B, then cherry-pick the commits you want from branch A. Which branch do you  have checked out?

Comment: i am doing same thing but its cherry-picks to same branch.and from where should i click to get tht cherry-pick option.now iam clicking on history so doing cherry checck-pick but its going to the same branch

Comment: Yes, so this is an eclipse problem, not a git problem. The easiest thing to do would be to open a command window and type in the commands to do this.